# Increment all nested values by given value in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

This my collections document looks like

```
 { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aae5caf0c7320224f375a58"), 
    "values" : {
        "a" : 20.0, 
        "b" : 15.0,
        "c" : 13.0
    }
}
```

and i want update this document by incrementing values of values object
so i want to update values object by incrementing to

```
"values" : {
        "a" :5.5, 
        "b" : 12.0,
        "c" : 6.0
    }
```

so i want to update using its update query with $inc parameter

```
db.collection.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5aae5caf0c7320224f375a58")},{"$inc":{"values" : {
            "a" :5.5, 
            "b" : 12.0,
            "c" : 6.0
        }}})
```

but it is not working, by workaround it it get to know that it can be used as below so it will work

```
db.collection.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5aae5caf0c7320224f375a58")},{"$inc":{"values.a" : 5.5,
                "values.b" : 12.0,
                "values.c" : 6.0
            }})
```

but i don't know how to do that in nodeJs
because i have lots of values in the values object so how to do that with javascript??
Thanks in advance